# Let $X$ be a random variable with pdf , $f_X(x)=e^{-x}$, $X>0$. Find the pdf of $Y=1/X^5$

Tags: calculus, probability

Let $X$ be a random variable with pdf , $f_X(x)=e^{-x}$, $X>0$.

Find the pdf of $Y=1/X^5$

Comment: What have you tried?  For example using the CDFs?

Answer (score -2):

$$ P(Y \le y) = P(X \ge y^{-1/5}) = \int_{y^{-1/5}}^{\infty} e^{-x} dx = \exp(-y^{-1/5}), \ y > 0.$$

Hence,
$$f_Y (y) = \frac{d}{dy} P(Y \le y) = \frac{1}{5} y^{-6/5} \exp(-y^{-1/5}), \ y >  0.$$